# Error when using webpack with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, webpack

I'm just starting to use Webpack, and I have an issue when I try to use jQuery with it. I'm a very newbie with Webpack, so please apologize if my question seems very basic.

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");
var bower_dir = __dirname + "/public/js/bower_components";
var compiled_dir = __dirname + "/public/js/compiled";

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        signup: compiled_dir + "/signup"
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $ : "jquery",
            jQuery : "jquery",
            "window.jQuery" : "jquery",
            "root.jQuery" : "jquery"
        })
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            jquery : bower_dir + "/jquery/src/jquery",
        }
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "public/js/dist"),
        filename: "[name].bundle.js"
    }

};
```

As I'm using ProvidePlugin (for jQuery plugins), I have no require("jquery") at the begininng of my file.
However, at execution, I get this output on the console :

> TypeError: jQuery.expr is undefined
>   http://localhost:9000/js/dist/signup.bundle.js
>   Line 6250

Do you have any clue ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you install jquery with npm by any chance? It would be a lot easier since webpack prefers it.

Comment: just tried it, and it doesn't work too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by removing "resolve" section in webpack.config.js and by installing jquery with npm.
However, if someone could explain me why it works now, I would be very grateful :-)

Comment: Not sure what's going on here but I hit the same issue. This comment fixed it for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue with an earlier/current version of JQuery, according to this issue raised here - https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1066.

To summarize from the above link, JQuery uses RequireJS, which has an implementation of AMD different from that of the actual AMD spec. This might be fixed in later versions. For now, try using the dist folder, which works just fine as well.
Just change this line here -

```
alias: {
        jquery : bower_dir + "/jquery/src/jquery",
    }
```

to this -

```
alias: {
        jquery : bower_dir + "/jquery/dist/jquery",
    }
```

In the meantime, there is a Webpack loader to fix this, and also a tutorial on how to use it, by Alexander O'Mara -

https://github.com/AlexanderOMara/amd-define-factory-patcher-loader
http://alexomara.com/blog/webpack-and-jquery-include-only-the-parts-you-need/